# Simple way to apply a list of functions to a value

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Suppose I've got a list of functions `List[A => B]` and need a function that returns `List[B]` for a given value of type `A`:

```
def foo[A, B](fs: List[A => B]): A => List[B] = a => fs.map(_.apply(a))
```

Is there any simpler (maybe with `cats`) way to write `List[A => B] => A => List[B]` ?

Comment: You can do `a => fs ap List(a)` with `cats` or just write `fs.map(_(a))`, but I doubt it is really making it simpler.

Comment: I concur it maybe does not make it simple but it's good to know anyway ! So, thank you, Oleg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Oleg points out, you can use `Applicative` to generate the function:

```
import cats.implicits._

def foo[A, B](fs: List[A => B]): A => List[B] = a => fs ap List(a)
```

Although I don't think it makes much of a difference in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `f (a -> b) -> a -> f b` suggests to use `flap` (from Haskell).

Starting from 2.9.0 you can use its equivalent in Cats named `mapApply`.

```scala
import cats.implicits._

def foo[A, B](fs: List[A => B]): A => List[B] = a => fs.mapApply(a)
```