# How to apply a function to a matrix?

Tags: scala, matrix, applicative, scala-cats

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160406/simple-way-to-apply-a-list-of-functions-to-a-value)

Now I know that `cats` provides an instance of `Apply` for `Vector`. So I can write:

```
import cats.implicits._

scala> val f: Int => Int = _ + 2
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> Vector(f) ap Vector(1, 2, 3)
res18: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(3, 4, 5)
```

Now I wonder how apply to `f` to all elements of a matrix defined as `Vector[Vector[Int]`. Does `cats` provide an `Apply` instance for matrices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `ap` on `Vector[Vector[Int]]`, you'll need `f` lifted to a `Vector[Vector[A => B]]`. One possible way is:

```
import cats.Apply
import cats.implicits._

val f: Int => Int = _ + 2
val vectorOfVectors = Apply[Vector] compose Apply[Vector]
val vec = Vector(Vector(1,2), Vector(3,4))
val res: Vector[Vector[Int]] = vectorOfVectors.ap(Vector(Vector(f)))(vec)
```

Yields:

```
Vector(3, 4)
Vector(5, 6)
```

A nicer way IMO is to use `Nested`:

Using `kind-projector` in `build.sbt`:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.9.4")
```

And then:

```
import cats.Functor
import cats.data.Nested
import cats.implicits._

val f: Int => Int = _ + 2
val vec = Vector(Vector(1,2), Vector(3,4))
val nested: Nested[Vector, Vector, Int] = Nested(vec)
val res: Nested[Vector, Vector, Int] = Functor[Nested[Vector, Vector, ?]].map(nested)(f)
val result: Vector[Vector[Int]] = res.value
```

Note how using `Nested` means we can apply `f` with no lifting at all.

Comment: Thank you. Now I got how it works in `cats` but I would prefer something like `Matrix(f) ap Matrix(...)`. I will check how they define `Martix` in `spire`.

Comment: Well ... I see they do not provide matrices in `spire`. So one probably need to use `breeze` or other libraries that are unlikely to provide `Apply` instance for their matrices implementations. It's getting very complicated then.