# Applicative style using cats library

Tags: scala, applicative, scala-cats

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160406/simple-way-to-apply-a-list-of-functions-to-a-value):

Suppose I want to use `Applicative` to apply function `A => B => C` to `List[A]` and `List[B]`.
I believe it looks like that in Haskell:

```
pure f <*> as <*> bs // apply f to List[A] and List[B]
```

or

```
f <$> as <*> bs
```

Does `cats` provide such a syntax? How would you write it with `cats` ?

Comment: `pure f <*> x <*> y` is just the same as `f <$> x <*> y`, where `(<$>)` is a synonym for `fmap`. I don't know Scala's syntax, or anything about `cats`, but from your linked question you seem to know where to find `fmap` and `(<*>)` already, so you should be able to just use them. If an infix synonym for `fmap` doesn't already exist I imagine you can define one, if you want the Scala syntax to look more like the target Haskell expression.

Comment: Alternatively, `f <$> x <*> y` is also the same as `liftA2 f x y`. From http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Apply.html, it looks to me like `cats` defines this function and calls it `map2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some definitions first

```
import cats._, implicits._
val as = List(1, 2)
val bs = List("a", "b")
```

## Curried funciton

If you have curried function, e.g.

```
val f = (i: Int) => (s: String) => Vector.fill(i)(s).mkString("")
```

Then `pure f <*> as <*> bs` expression is directly translated to cats as

```
f.pure[List].ap(as).ap(bs)
```

---

And `f <$> as <*> bs` becomes

```
as.map(f).ap(bs)
```

Yes, the order is not as natural anymore.

---

## Uncurried function

In Scala very often you will deal with the functions taking multiple parameters:

```
val f2 = (i: Int, s: String) => Vector.fill(i)(s).mkString("")
// or val f2 = Function.uncurried(f)
```

For these, `cats` provides `CartesianBuilder` syntax:

```
(as |@| bs).map(f2)
```

Or, in the newer versions, tuple syntax with `map#` method (that is subject to be renamed, IIRC)

```
(as, bs).map2(f2)
```

All these snippets evaluate to `List("a", "b", "aa", "bb")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for.